# copyToRange (and similar) execution at end of script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a kinda large sheet which I would like to update on a regular basis (weekly) via Google Apps Scripts.
Every week I need to add a new column at the "end" (lastDataColumn) of my sheet and then move the last two colums (with Fomulas to calculate weekly relative changes) to the "end" (ie move them one column to the right). This leaves me with a blank column addressed with lastDataColumn - 2. This is where the new report data will go.

I have two functions.
copyCols and getReports.

They both work fine on their own, so copyCols creates a new empty column at position lastDataColumn - 2 using the method explained above -  and getReports fetches report Data from Analytics, third party APIs and other sheets and then writes these values in the column at position lastDataColumn - 2.

However, if I group these two functions in let's say my main function which I then want to trigger on a 7-day basis, copyCols seems to only execute to the point of creating a new empty column. Then getReports executes fully and writes all data in lastDataColumn - 2. But no columns were moved, so getReports overwrites last weeks data. After executing everything from getReports copyCols starts moving the rows (ie copying). 
This leaves me with a duplicate column of lastDataColumn - 3 (which should have last weeks data, but was overwritten with this weeks data because it was still in lastDataColumn - 2 before the execution of getReports) in lastDataColumn - 2.

**To clarify: Executing copyCols and getReports afterwards (each on it's own) works perfectly fine.**

Is Google Apps Script threadless? If so why does the problem described happen? Do "bulk" operations (like copying ranges) execute at the end of the script?

Code:

```
var today = new Date();
var start = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var end = new Date(today.getTime() - 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var dateString=Utilities.formatDate(start, Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd.MM.')+'-'+Utilities.formatDate(end, Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd.MM.')

var nc=2 //num of cols with growth rates to move

function main() {
  copyCols();
  getReports();
}

function copyCols(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1dSpy7teczLwViKbfr-VjfQRuOq3iaRfSm3LghFldjZk')
  var sh_DB=ss.getSheetByName('data')
  var w=sh_DB.getLastColumn(); //width
  var h = sh_DB.getLastRow();  //heigth
  // insert new column
  sh_DB.insertColumnAfter(w);
  // copy last n cols to next col
  for (i=0;i<=nc;i++){
    sh_DB.getRange(1,w-i,h,1).copyTo(sh_DB.getRange(1,w-i+1,h,1));
  }
  sh_DB.getRange(1,w-nc+1).setValue(dateString);
}

function getReports(){
  var sh_DB=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('data')
  var w=sh_DB.getLastColumn(); //width
  var h = sh_DB.getLastRow();  //heigth
  dc=sh_DB.getRange(1,w-nc); //lastDataColumn
  data = [50, 60, 870, 2];
  report = {'rows':[2,3,4,5]};
  for (i in data){
    sh_DB.getRange(report['rows'][i],w-nc).setValue(data[i]);
  } 
}
```

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Can you take a look at the execution transcript and see if there are any errors related to maximum execution time  because app script is not very good for handling large amount of data in spreadsheets and can be slow at processing it ?

Comment: No problems with the execution protocoll... in addition to my post - according to the excution transscript copyToRange is executed right when it's called (not at the end like it looks with the order changes are being made in the sheet) and without any problem inducing execution time (zero point something seconds).

Comment: Please insert a `Logger.log("Copy exec # :" + i);` in the `for loop` for `// copy last n cols to next col` in the function `copyCols()` and see what does the log say when `copyCols()` is actually called from `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) between `copyCols()` and `getReports()` in order to tell to the Google Apps Script engine to apply the changes made by the first before running the second.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I never read about this in the documentation. Is there any way I can tell which operations are bundled together?

Comment: AFAIK no, but instead of doing loops for doing multiple calls to the SpreadsheetApp classes, get/set multiple values at once, i.e. instead of  `.setValue(value)` use `.setValues(values)`.